# Parallel processing the same data in separeted branch

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I'm trying separate the work on frames to a few parallel pipeline branch. Let's say we have this pipeline:

```
some_merger_frames_by_ts ! autovideosink 
v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! tee name=t 
t. ! queue ! /*some work with received frame*/ ! some_merger_frames_by_ts.
t. ! queue ! /*some work with received frame*/ ! some_merger_frames_by_ts.
```

The same work is being doing on every branch. I couldn't found anything like some_merger_frames_by_ts with the nedeed functionality. I've been searching a lot, but couldn't found anything needed.
I want to filter frames in each queue by ts, and then merge them in some_merger_frames_by_ts and get aligned stream.

Really, had no one tried?

Is this possible? Any help or alternative approaches would be much appreciated.

Thank a lot in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for `GstAggregator` https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/base/gstaggregator.html?gi-language=c ?

Comment: @FlorianZwoch, thank you the quick answer! Hmm... I'm not sure. Could you describe your idea in more detail, please? First of all, I have no idea how split input frames on different branches.